# Updating row based on values in previous rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

Consider a table with below columns and sample data:

```
id  key Week-end  n-11 n-10 n-9 n-8 n-7 n-6 n-5 n-4 n-3 n-2 n-1 n
255 696 10/31/2013                                              7
255 696 11/14/2013                                              6
255 696 11/28/2013                                              2
255 696 12/12/2013                                              5
255 696 12/26/2013                                              
255 696 1/9/2014                                                6
255 696 1/23/2014                                               
255 696 1/30/2014                                               8
255 696 1/16/2014                                               9
255 696 1/2/2014                                                5
255 696 12/19/2013                                              
255 696 12/5/2013                                               3
255 696 11/21/2013                                              
255 696 11/7/2013
```

There are multiple id and key combination with value of `‘n’` prepopulated. But for each unique `key` and `id` combination and weekend in ascending order, values of remaining column needs to be filled.
For every row, `n-1` indicates the value of `‘n’` for previous week , `n-2` indicate the value of `‘n’` two weeks before and so on.  Only previous 11 values of n needs to be considered for each row and the record having no values needs to be filled with `null`. Following is the required output

```
id  key Week-end  n-11 n-10 n-9 n-8 n-7 n-6 n-5 n-4 n-3 n-2 n-1 n
255 696 10/31/2013                                              7
255 696 11/7/2013                                           7   
255 696 11/14/2013                                      7       6
255 696 11/21/2013                                  7       6   
255 696 11/28/2013                              7       6       2
255 696 12/5/2013                           7       6       2   3
255 696 12/12/2013                      7       6       2   3   5
255 696 12/19/2013                  7       6       2   3   5   
255 696 12/26/2013              7       6       2   3   5       
255 696 1/2/2014            7       6       2   3   5           5
255 696 1/9/2014        7       6       2   3   5           5   6
255 696 1/16/2014   7       6       2   3   5           5   6   9
255 696 1/23/2014       6       2   3   5           5   6   9   
255 696 1/30/2014   6       2   3   5           5   6   9       8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no gap in your source data, you can obtain the required result with the [`LAG`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions082.htm#i1327527) analytic function:

```
SQL> SELECT ID, k, weekend,
  2          --
  3         LAG(n, 11) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, k ORDER BY weekend) "n-11",
  4         LAG(n, 10) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, k ORDER BY weekend) "n-10",
  5         LAG(n, 9) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, k ORDER BY weekend) "n-9",
  6         LAG(n, 8) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, k ORDER BY weekend) "n-8",
  7         LAG(n, 7) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, k ORDER BY weekend) "n-7",
  8         LAG(n, 6) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, k ORDER BY weekend) "n-6",
  9         LAG(n, 5) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, k ORDER BY weekend) "n-5",
 10         LAG(n, 4) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, k ORDER BY weekend) "n-4",
 11         LAG(n, 3) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, k ORDER BY weekend) "n-3",
 12         LAG(n, 2) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, k ORDER BY weekend) "n-2",
 13         LAG(n, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, k ORDER BY weekend) "n-1",
 14          --
 15         n
 16    FROM TEST;

  ID    K WEEKEND     n-11 n-10  n-9  n-8  n-7  n-6  n-5  n-4  n-3  n-2  n-1    N
---- ---- ----------- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
 255  696 31/10/2013                                                            7
 255  696 07/11/2013                                                       7 
 255  696 14/11/2013                                                  7         6
 255  696 21/11/2013                                             7         6 
 255  696 28/11/2013                                        7         6         2
 255  696 05/12/2013                                   7         6         2    3
 255  696 12/12/2013                              7         6         2    3    5
 255  696 19/12/2013                         7         6         2    3    5 
 255  696 26/12/2013                    7         6         2    3    5      
 255  696 02/01/2014               7         6         2    3    5              5
 255  696 09/01/2014          7         6         2    3    5              5    6
 255  696 16/01/2014     7         6         2    3    5              5    6    9
 255  696 23/01/2014          6         2    3    5              5    6    9 
 255  696 30/01/2014     6         2    3    5              5    6    9         8
```

However, if there is a gap (a missing weekend for instance) this will return the wrong result. In this case, you'll have to be more specific with your windowing clause, for instance:

```
SQL> SELECT ID, k, weekend,
  2          --
  3         first_value(n) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, k ORDER BY weekend RANGE BETWEEN 7*11 PRECEDING AND 7*11 PRECEDING) "n-11",
  4         first_value(n) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, k ORDER BY weekend RANGE BETWEEN 7*10 PRECEDING AND 7*10 PRECEDING) "n-10",
  5         first_value(n) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, k ORDER BY weekend RANGE BETWEEN 7*9  PRECEDING AND 7*9  PRECEDING) "n-9",
  6         first_value(n) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, k ORDER BY weekend RANGE BETWEEN 7*8  PRECEDING AND 7*8  PRECEDING) "n-8",
  7         first_value(n) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, k ORDER BY weekend RANGE BETWEEN 7*7  PRECEDING AND 7*7  PRECEDING) "n-7",
  8         first_value(n) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, k ORDER BY weekend RANGE BETWEEN 7*6  PRECEDING AND 7*6  PRECEDING) "n-6",
  9         first_value(n) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, k ORDER BY weekend RANGE BETWEEN 7*5  PRECEDING AND 7*5  PRECEDING) "n-5",
 10         first_value(n) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, k ORDER BY weekend RANGE BETWEEN 7*4  PRECEDING AND 7*4  PRECEDING) "n-4",
 11         first_value(n) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, k ORDER BY weekend RANGE BETWEEN 7*3  PRECEDING AND 7*3  PRECEDING) "n-3",
 12         first_value(n) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, k ORDER BY weekend RANGE BETWEEN 7*2  PRECEDING AND 7*2  PRECEDING) "n-2",
 13         first_value(n) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, k ORDER BY weekend RANGE BETWEEN 7*1  PRECEDING AND 7*1  PRECEDING) "n-1",
 14          --
 15         n
 16    FROM TEST;

  ID    K WEEKEND     n-11 n-10  n-9  n-8  n-7  n-6  n-5  n-4  n-3  n-2  n-1    N
---- ---- ----------- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
 255  696 31/10/2013                                                            7
 255  696 07/11/2013                                                       7 
 255  696 14/11/2013                                                  7         6
 255  696 21/11/2013                                             7         6 
 255  696 28/11/2013                                        7         6         2
 255  696 05/12/2013                                   7         6         2    3
 255  696 12/12/2013                              7         6         2    3    5
 255  696 19/12/2013                         7         6         2    3    5 
 255  696 26/12/2013                    7         6         2    3    5      
 255  696 02/01/2014               7         6         2    3    5              5
 255  696 09/01/2014          7         6         2    3    5              5    6
 255  696 16/01/2014     7         6         2    3    5              5    6    9
 255  696 23/01/2014          6         2    3    5              5    6    9 
 255  696 30/01/2014     6         2    3    5              5    6    9         8
```